# If $F : Top \to C $ be a functor then following assertions are equivalent:

Tags: algebraic-topology

This proof was left as exercise in my class of topology and I am not able to make any significant progress on this question:

Question: Let $F : Top \to C$ be a functor. Then show that the following assertions
are equivalent: (i) for all continuous maps f, g if $f \simeq g$ then F(f) = F(g),
(ii) F sends the homotopy equivalences to isomorphisms in C.

Using the above result deduce that : If f is a homotopy equivalence, then $\pi_0(f)$ is a bijection. ( *This definition might be useful :For all topological spaces X, we let $\pi_0(X) $ denote the set of  arcwise connected components of X.  We let $\bar{x}$ denote the arcwise component of $x\in X$. For all continuous maps $f : X\to Y$ , then $\pi_0(f) : \pi_0(X) \to \pi_0(Y)$ is given by $\overline{x}\to \overline{f(x)}$.*)

Attempt: Two topological spaces are called homotopy equivalent if there exists a continuous maps $f : X\to Y$ and $g: Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g \simeq  id_Y$ and $g\circ f \simeq id_X$.

Let (i) holds. I think I have to prove that if f and g are homotopy equivalences and if they are composed with F, then they will be isomorphisms. for f and g there exists right and left inverse respectively but I am not able to show that if they are composed with F , then the function given will be isomorphism.  I have to show that F(f) and F(g) are isomorphisms. Composing $f\circ g =  id_Y$ and $ g\circ f =id_X$ with F, I will  get $F(f) \circ F(g) =id $ and $F(g)\circ F(f) =id$. But I am not able to move forward from this.

Let (ii) holds and I have $f\simeq g$ but I am not sure how can I show that $F(f)= F(g) $.

For the 3rd deduction: To show that $\pi_0 (f) $ is a bijection. Given , $f$ is a homotopy equivalence. There exists a map g such that $f\circ g= id_Y$ and $g\circ f =id_X$.  But I am not able to move forward from this. ( Actually , I can use (ii) to deduce this , but for it I will have to prove that (ii) is independently true and not just equivalent to (i).)

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: FYI, $F (f)$ is "applying $F$ to $f$", not "composing $F$ with $f$". As for your actual question: perhaps it is helpful to consider certain homotopy equivalences $X \times I \to X$...

Comment: @ZhenLin You are right.

Comment: Your definition of "homotopy equivalent" is wrong. You are confusing with "homeomorphic".

Comment: @AnneBauval See here:https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html I think my definition is fine.

Comment: The comment of @AnneBauval is correct. Homotopy equivalence requires the composite maps $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ to be homotopic (not necessarily equal) to identity maps.

Comment: @AndreasBlass So, is the definition given in Wolfram mathworld here :https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html ? My lecturer gave the same definition as written here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HomotopyEquivalence.html

Comment: The definition at your link agrees with what I wrote: homotopic to identity maps.

Comment: Moreover, the link  explicitely mentions that this property is strictly weaker than homeomorphism.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much for correcting me, can you please share a reference for correct definition. I shall be really grateful to you.

Comment: The Mathworld definition is correct. You changed it by writing $=$ where Mathworld had "homotopic to"; that change makes your definition wrong.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much!

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you very much for correcting me!

Comment: Please use descriptive titles

Answer (score 1):

"(i) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)"

> Composing $f\circ g =  id_Y$ and $ g\circ f =id_X$ with F, I will  get $F(f) \circ F(g) =id $ and $F(g)\circ F(f) =id$.

So there should be $f\circ g\simeq id_Y$ and $g\circ f\simeq id_X$ (instead of equalities), which doesn't change much, since by (i) and functoriality it indeed leads to $F(f)\circ F(g)=id$ and $F(g)\circ F(f)=id$.

> But I am not able to move forward from this.

What else is there to say? That's literally the definition of an isomorphism.

---

"(ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)"

This implication is a bit more complicated. First we need the following:

> **Definition.** Given a topological space $X$, by cylinder of $X$ we will understand a topological space $C$, together with two maps $i_1,i_2:X\to C$ and a homotopy equivalence $p:C\to X$ such that $p\circ i_1=id_X$ and $p\circ i_2=id_X$.

Then we have:

> **Lemma.** Two maps $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopy equivalent if and only if there is a cylinder $(C,i_1,i_2,p)$ for $X$ with a map $H:C\to Y$ such that $H\circ i_1=f$ and $H\circ i_2=g$.

For proof see the answer to that question: [Is there any analogy between homotopy of spaces and homotopy between maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3288531/is-there-any-analogy-between-homotopy-of-spaces-and-homotopy-between-maps)

How do we apply our lemma? Assume that $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopy equivalent. By our lemma we have $i_1$, $i_2$, $p$ and $H$ as above. With this we have

$$F(f)=F(H\circ i_1)=F(H)\circ F(i_1)$$

Now $p$ is a homotopy equivalence and thus $F(p)$ is an isomorphism by (ii). Meaning $F(p)^{-1}$ exists. So

$$F(f)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(i_1)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(p)^{-1}\circ F(p)\circ F(i_1)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(p)^{-1}\circ F(p\circ i_1)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(p)^{-1}\circ F(id_X)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(p)^{-1}\circ F(p\circ i_2)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(p)^{-1}\circ F(p)\circ F(i_2)=$$
$$=F(H)\circ F(i_2)=$$
$$=F(H\circ i_2)=$$
$$=F(g)$$

---

> If f is a homotopy equivalence, then $\pi_0(f)$ is a bijection.

For that we would like to apply "(i)$\Rightarrow$(ii)" implication, and so we need to prove that $\pi_0$ preserves homotopies first.

So assume that $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopy equivalent. That means there is a homotopy $H:I\times X\to Y$ connecting $f$ to $g$. Now given $x\in X$ this gives us a path $\lambda:I\to Y$, $\lambda(t)=H(t,x)$. This path connects $f(x)$ with $g(x)$. Meaning $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ share the same path component. Or in other words $\overline{f(x)}=\overline{g(x)}$ in your notation. By the arbitrary choice of $x$ we conclude that $\pi_0(f)=\pi_0(g)$.